# Grab TextView (in a ListVIew Row ) from ContextMenu

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu

I know to get a string of a specific `TextView` in a `ListView`, I can do this:

```
ReviewUser = ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelUser))
                .getText().toString();
```

What if I want to get the `TextView` itself?

The `TextView` is an integer and I simply want to get the `TextView` and add `1` to it.

Comment: Does your code not get the TextView anyways? Also your TextView cannot be an integer, a TextView is an Object, not a primitive data type.

Comment: Well I was going to do something like this:  `tv.setText(Integer.valueOf(num) + 1)`

Comment: Well where are you getting num from? Also my statement still stands, since you are already accessing the TextView when you do `rowView.findViewById()` everything else should work.

Comment: Oh, the `TextView` value is populated through an Adapter, sorry.  Also, I see where you are saying, so to grab the value, I just do: `tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById()`?  Or should I be getting the String value of the `TextView`, increment it, and set THAT back to `TextView`?

Comment: You're not grabbing a value with findViewById, you're grabbing the TextView whose text you want to change. So basically do that and the second part of your above comment.

Comment: I'll try.. put that as an answer if you wish and I'd be happy to credit you on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already specified that you know how to get the specific text from your ListView. Since you want to modify that same TextView, the rest is simple. This code is lengthier just to show the steps.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.labelUser)
String text = textView.getText().toString();
int num = Integer.valueOf (text).intValue() + 1;
textView.setText (""+num);
```

Also, if you are working with a String ArrayAdapter and you know the index of the row you want to modify, what you can do is (assuming arrayAdapter is initialized and index is your index variable):

```
String text = arrayAdapter.get(index);
arrayAdapter.remove (text);
arrayAdapter.insert ((Integer.valueOf (text).intValue() + 1 ) + "", index);
```

Comment: That is what I did as well.  Thanks for getting me in right direction.